# How do you cross-correlate audio files to see if a sample matches the original?

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

I'm trying to write a function in MATLAB that can match a ten second audio sample to the audio file that it came from, out of 39 audio files. I need to search through a directory of audio files to find the file that my sample came from. I know I need to use the xcorr function in some way but I can't figure out how to read through the directory to make the comparison. Basicaly I need to:

Read an audio file

See if my sample is from the current audio file

If it is, I need the file number (out of 39), as well as where in the file my sample occurs

If not I need to move on to the next file

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A broad overview of this process involves doing the cross-correlation between each signal and the ten second sample. After doing the cross-correlation we find take the maximum, `max()` which will give us a factor of "best fit" (most correlation) for each of the comparisons. We then take the maximum result of the peak-correlations to find which of the signals fits the best. The script below uses a structure, `struct` to hold the significant data such as the audio signals, cross-correlation and peak-correlation. I've only tested my sample against 3 audio files, so the results might differ when attempting 39, but it should work to the best of my knowledge. To stop playing the sound simply type `clear sound` in the command window.

---

### Steps:

• Read the audio file names from a folder/directory using `dir()`.

• Read the ten second audio sample and the files in the folder using the `audioread()` function.

• Compare the signals using the `xcorr()` function and compute the peak-correlation for the comparison using the `max()` function.

• Find which comparison had the highest peak-correlation by using the `max()` function on the peak correlation array.

• Keep in mind I only used the left channel so you might have to test against both channels if your audio is not the same for both channel or mono.

---

### Full Script:

```
%Loading ten second audio sample%
Ten_Second_Sample = audioread("Sample.mp3");
Audio_Properties = audioinfo("Sample.mp3");
Sampling_Frequency = Audio_Properties.SampleRate;

%Grabbing all the mp3 and mp4 file names in a folder named "Audio Folder"%
Folder_Name = 'Audio Folder';
Audio_Files = [dir(fullfile(Folder_Name,'*mp3')); dir(fullfile(Folder_Name,'*m4a'))];

%Creating a structure to hold all the audio data and cross-correlation
%results%
Audio_Signals = struct("Signal",[],"Cross_Correlation",[],"Peak_Correlation",[]);

%Evaluting the cross-correlation and peak-correlation between the audio and ten second sample%
for Audio_Index = 1: length(Audio_Files)
Audio_Signals(Audio_Index).Signal = audioread(fullfile('Audio Folder/',Audio_Files(Audio_Index).name));
Left_Channel = Audio_Signals(Audio_Index).Signal(:,1);
Audio_Signals(Audio_Index).Cross_Correlation = xcorr(Left_Channel,Ten_Second_Sample(:,1));
Audio_Signals(Audio_Index).Peak_Correlation = max(Audio_Signals(Audio_Index).Cross_Correlation);
end

%Evaluating the highest peak correlation among the compared signals%
Peak_Correlations = [Audio_Signals.Peak_Correlation].';
[~,Index] = max(Peak_Correlations);
disp(Audio_Files(Index).name);
sound(Audio_Signals(Index).Signal,Sampling_Frequency);
```

Comment: Note: I didn't implement the breaking process as soon as audio file is found as it maybe difficult to judge a threshold for best fit/most correlated without relaying throughout the entire dataset.

Comment: For Audio_files all my files are mp4's so would I then use the code Audio_Files = [dir(fullfile(Folder_Name,'*mp4'));

Comment: I thought `mp4's` are video files though?

Comment: My bad, they are mp3's. I can't read apparently